# Fetch API post data not receiving in Django view

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, fetch-api

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to send a post request with data to a Django view using fetch API like this:

*javascript:*

```
const data = {
  search_text: "",
  months: 6,
  property_type: "all"
};
const headers = {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
}

fetch("some-url", {method: "POST", headers: headers, body: JSON.stringify(data)})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

*views.py:*

```
class MyView(View):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     print("request: ", request.POST)
     # do stuff with post data
```

*urls.py:*

```
re_path(r"^my_view/$", login_required(csrf_exempt(MyView.as_view())), name="my_view"),
```

**Problem**

When I try to access the post data in my Django view I get empty QueryDict and the output of the terminal is this:

```
request:  <QueryDict: {}>
[06/Jan/2022 06:48:19] "POST /my_app/my_view/ HTTP/1.1" 200 114
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/
[06/Jan/2022 06:48:22] "{"search_text":"","months":"6","property_type":"all"}GET /inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/?max=5 HTTP/1.1" 403 12291
```

If you notice at the last line the post data seems to get added in the terminal why is that happening ? also why I get Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) even when I am using `csrf_exempt` in the urls ?

I have tried looking it up and nothing seems to work. We are using react and I know axios can also be used but it should work with fetch API why isn't it working please help.

**Edit:**

Even after adding csrf token like mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/) and removing `csrf_exempt` from the urls I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay fixed the issue it seems the data I was looking for was not in `request.POST` but instead in `request.body` did the following changes:

```
import json

class MyView(View):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     print("request: ", json.loads(request.body))
     # do stuff with post data
```

`request.body` returns byte string so need to convert that to json with `json.loads` for more info read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your view is protected by a [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf)-protection-middleware.

You have two possibilities:

- Make the view exempt from this protection, see [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)
- Add the CSRF token to your request (see answer from Yevgeniy Kosmak)

Comment: I am already suing csrf_exempt check my question carefully

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 problems:

1. Add the `X-CSRFToken` to your fetch request and the a function to get csrftoken from cookies:

**getCSRFToken** function

```
function getCSRFToken() {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, 10) == ('csrftoken' + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(10));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

const csrftoken = getCSRFToken();
```

**fetch**

```
const data = {
  search_text: "",
  months: 6,
  property_type: "all"
};
const headers = {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
   'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken, // new option
}

fetch("some-url", {
    method: "POST", 
    headers: headers, 
    body: JSON.stringify(data)}
).then(
    (response) => response.json()
).then(
    (data) => console.log(data)
);
```

2. In `MyView` class retrieve data with `json.loads()` from `request.body` and return a json response:

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     print("posted data is: ", json.loads(request.body))
     # do stuff with post data
```